# Sql query to show name not starting with vowels

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table test(
id int,
name char(10)
);
insert into test values(1,'sukesh');
insert into test values(2,'ramesh');
insert into test values(3,'adkjdf');
insert into test values(4,'eeuf');
insert into test values(5,'hdkjdf');
insert into test values(6,'nhkjdf');
insert into test values(7,'pdkjdf');
insert into test values(8,'adkjdf');
insert into test values(9,'oeruw');
insert into test values(10,'iblesjf');

SELECT * FROM test
WHERE name  LIKE '[!aeiou]%';
```

Here is what i tried but it out put is showing as
Program did not output anything!

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: LIKE does not support regular expressions (at least in the SQL standard). Additionally: the negation of a regex set would be `^` not `!`

Comment: @JonasMetzler Mysql

Comment: I would simply use LEFT (name, 1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u') here, but this question is really a pure duplicate, see the link by @mmh4all

Answer (score 0):

create table test(
id int,
name char(10)
);
insert into test values(1,'sukesh'),(2,'ramesh'),(3,'adkjdf'),
(4,'eeuf'),(5,'hdkjdf'),(6,'nhkjdf'),(7,'pdkjdf')

SELECT * FROM test
WHERE name NOT LIKE '[!aeiou]%'; -- Put 'NOT' CLAUSE BEFORE 'LIKE'